# Creating a table with just 2 columns

Tags: tables

I have the following table

```
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Parameter & Economic Interpretation\\  \hline
$\beta$ & Discount Factor\\  \hline
    $\delta$ & Capital's Depreciation Rate\\ \hline
    $\eta$ & Growth Rate of Labour Augmenting Technology\\ \hline
    $\theta$ & Capital's share in Output& \\ \hline
    $\rho$ & Technology Shock's Persistence\\ \hline
    $A$ & Steady-State for Technology Shock\\ \hline
    $\gamma$ & Proportion of Disutility of Hours Worked\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

My objective is to remove the extra column that shows in the pdf... However, when I change `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}` to `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}` I get the following error:

> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed
>   to \cr.

Is there a way to remedy this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was only a typo.

Comment: @Sveinung fair enough ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a `&` too much in the 5th row:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Parameter & Economic Interpretation\\  \hline
$\beta$ & Discount Factor\\  \hline
    $\delta$ & Capital's Depreciation Rate\\ \hline
    $\eta$ & Growth Rate of Labour Augmenting Technology\\ \hline
    $\theta$ & Capital's share in Output \\ \hline
    $\rho$ & Technology Shock's Persistence\\ \hline
    $A$ & Steady-State for Technology Shock\\ \hline
    $\gamma$ & Proportion of Disutility of Hours Worked\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Upssss... Thanks ;)